# NSURLSession didReceiveData called continuously for same request with same response

Tags: ios, nsurlsession, nsurlsessiondatatask

```
- (void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session dataTask:(NSURLSessionDataTask *)dataTask didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
}
```

The above delegate method is called repeatedly so that the below delegate method is not called and app is hanged because of that.

```
- (void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session task:(NSURLSessionTask *)task
didCompleteWithError:(nullable NSError *)error
{
}
```

Methods used to create NSURLSessionDataTask

```
-(void)fetchDataAboveiOS7:(NSMutableURLRequest*)request :(void(^)(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error))completionHandler
{
    __block NSURLSessionDataTask *task;

    task = [[self getSessionConfiguration] dataTaskWithRequest:request];

    __block  NSMutableArray *networkError;
    if (!networkError) {
        networkError = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    }

    [task setTaskDescription:[request allHTTPHeaderFields][kTempId]];
    [task resume];
}

-(NSURLSession *)getSessionConfiguration {

    if (self.session) {
        return self.session;
    }

    NSURLSessionConfiguration *config = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
    config.timeoutIntervalForRequest = kRequestTimeOut;
    config.allowsCellularAccess = YES;
    config.HTTPMaximumConnectionsPerHost = kMaximumConnectionPerHost;
    config.requestCachePolicy = NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData;
    self.session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:config delegate:self delegateQueue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]];

    return self.session;
}
```

Additional Code which used for creating NSURLRequest and this object is sent to fetchDataAboveiOS7

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request=[NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:_url
                                                         cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy
                                                     timeoutInterval:timeOutInterval];

    /*method*/
    [request setHTTPMethod:method];

    if (self.sessionCookie != nil) {
        [request setValue:self.sessionCookie forHTTPHeaderField:kCookie];
    }

NSMutableDictionary *headerDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
        [headerDict setValue:@"application/json;charset=UTF-8" forKey:@"Accept"];
        [headerDict setValue:@"application/json;charset=UTF-8" forKey:@"Content-Type"];


        for (NSString *key in [headerDict allKeys])
        {
            [request addValue:[headerDict valueForKey:key] forHTTPHeaderField:key];
        }

        if (bodyDict)
        {
            [request setHTTPBody:[NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:bodyDict
                                                                 options:kNilOptions error:&error]];
        }

[self fetchDataAboveiOS7:request :^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {

}];
```

Comment: Post the code where you create and run the `NSURLSessionDataTask`

Comment: @mag_zbc : Please see the edited code

Comment: You need to show the code that calls `fetchDataAboveiOS7`

Comment: @mag_zbc : Due to confidentiality issue I can't share the whole code, but I have shared the code which is used to create NSURLRequest. And that request is sent to function fetchDataAboveiOS7

Comment: In general this method is called multiple times for large data with the same request and response. You should collect all the data until the complete method is called. Checked this received data for errors.